# Best roof for tropical climate

Tags: roof

I'm building a new house and can't decide what type of roof is best. I live in a tropical country where the day temperature is always above 32 degrees celcius. The criteria I want for the roof are:
- doesn't turn my house into an oven
- zero or low maintenance 
- less leak problems
- no pests
- better performance during earthquake

I intially wanted a hip, tile roof, but I hesitate at the thoughts of having to clean the gutter often and rats getting inside the ceiling.

Your feedback will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of corrugated steel roofs.  They are noisy in a rain, especially if you have the windows open, and have little or no insulation in the ceiling space. They are quieter if they are firmly attached to mass:  E.g. a steel roof over 3/4" OSB over trusses will be quieter than steel over 2x4 purlons over truss.

Steel roofs are commonly done on trusses at 4 foot spacing here for machine sheds  Roofing fluctuates a lot in price, but my latest shed it was 2.35 Canadian per running foot 3 feet wide.  Call it 80 cents per square foot.  They last about 40-50 years.  Nowadays you can get them in a large variety of colours.  In a tropical climate I would get white, or very pale yellow.

In a tropical climate I would consider very oversize trusses so that you have and 8-10 foot overhang all the way around.  This reduces solar heating, and gives you a bunch of outdoor space that normally doesn't get wet.

Comment: ...but beware of hurricane uplift if in a part of the tropics subject to that sort of thing, especially with lots of extra overhang.

Comment: Standing Seam Metal -- you won't regret it (other than the cost).